# Implementing a dead reckoning application using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I need to implement a dead reckoning application using xamarin. In order to do this, I need to access the pedometer/accelerometer from Android/ios and windows phone. Since they have their own APIs to be called, I believe the approach would be to create an interface in the PCL project and then have native implementations for each platform. These could then be made visible using assemblies. Apart from this, are there any approaches using which the entire code can be implemented in the PCL project itself? Without having native implementations for each platform?

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your app can be done in the PCL but calling the pedometer or accelerometer must be done natively.

The basic approach is (just an example)

```cs
public interface IPedometer
{
    int GetSteps();
}
```

and this interface is in your PCL.

On each native platform create a class (e.g. NativePedometer), implement this interface and natively code to get the result.

Use dependency injection on each native platform, e.g.

```cs
DependencyService.Register<NativePedometer>();
```

Then just use the below in your PCL.

`DependencyService.Get<IPedometer>()` and perform the business logic in your PCL. This allows you to reuse as much code as possible across platforms.

It is the best approach but you can't avoid writing native code and by native code I mean C# in the traditional/native Xamarin projects.

Comment: James Montemagno has a step counter. Heaps of examples when googling for the native implementations. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/My-StepCounter